# Warning: Illegal string offset 'code' in /path/ on line 17

Tags: php, arrays, json

I keep getting the error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'code' in /path/ on line 17". I have tried many things but don't know what the problem is. Here is my code:

```
require_once 'unirest-php-master/src/Unirest.php';

$response = Unirest\Request::post("https://andruxnet-random-famous-
quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "key",
    "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
  )
);

$encoded = json_encode($response,true);
echo $encoded['code'];
```

This code is being used to get information from the api and it is successfully getting the information but when I try to access an object in the array I get an error.

I have also tried to use json_decode instead of encode but that gives me an error about parameter 1 needing to be a string

Edit: line 17 is this line: echo $encoded['code'];

Comment: `in /path/ on line 17` - is this line part of the code you posted?

Comment: Sorry I should have made that more clear. line 17 is this line 'echo $encoded['code'];'

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it seems like you want to print the response obtained from API (in JSON format). So, you should be doing json_decode here.

```
var_dump($response); // Check response obtained from API

$encoded = json_decode($response,true); // Change to json_decode
echo "<pre>"; print_r($encoded); // Debug decoded array

echo $encoded['code']; // Check data
```

Comment: Instead I get the following error: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /path/ on line 16

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($response); die;` ?

Comment: `object(Unirest\Response)#1 (4) { ["code"]=> int(200) ["raw_body"]=> string(144) "{"quote":"One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas, I don't know.","author":"Animal Crackers","category":"Movies"}" ["body"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["quote"]=> string(85) "One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas, I don't know." ["author"]=> string(15) "Animal Crackers" ["category"]=> string(6) "Movies" } ["headers"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ["Content-Type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" ["Date"]=> string(29) "Sat,`

Comment: I had to shorten it due to character limits

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The first thing I did wrong was try to decode or encode it, I didn't need to do either. I was also using ["code"] rather than ->code